# Need help from expert>< Any way can help to auto allocate data into cells based on certain criteria[refer to hyperlink for photo explaination]

Tags: excel-formula

[i'm trying to allocate those supply into my demand. The supply will be allocate by FIFO according to the ready date. Is there any formula or script can help to perform those auto allocation instead of manually allocate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSPkh.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

=INDEX($A$6:$D$7;MATCH(F12;$D$6:$D$7;0);1)

[image]